# How do I use the latest Sass and Compass?

Tags: ruby

I've had problems with multiple ruby versions installed, couldn't install animation gem properly. The latest Compass has it included so it might solve it for me. I don't need ruby for anything else so ruby version isn't important for me.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

animation (0.1.alpha.3)
chunky_png (1.2.8)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
i18n (0.7.0)
multi_json (1.11.2)
oily_png (1.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.4.18, 3.2.12)


$ sass -v 
Sass 3.4.18 (Selective Steve)


$ compass -v 
Errno::ENOENT on line ["25"] of /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/version.rb: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/../../VERSION.yml
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same error as @prkos, this is a know bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-compass/+bug/1100018

Please try: `sudo gem install compass`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, not sure why now.

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

animation (0.1.alpha.3)
chunky_png (1.2.8)
compass (1.0.3, 0.12.2)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
i18n (0.7.0)
multi_json (1.11.2)
oily_png (1.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.4.18, 3.2.12)

$ sass -v 
Sass 3.4.18 (Selective Steve)

$ compass -v 
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2016 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass